# HTTP request delays one user input in angular

Tags: angular

I'm finding some difficulties with the following issue.

I've 2 dropdown menus:

```
<h1>Change the inbound rates</h1>
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Carriers</mat-label>
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="setCarrier($event.source.value)">
    <mat-option matInput required placeholder="label" *ngFor="let carrier of rateCards" [value]="carrier.carrierId">
      {{carrier.carrierName}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field floatLabel="never" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Ledger</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="ledgerName">
    <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="setLedger(ledgerName)" matInput required placeholder="label" *ngFor="let ledger of nameDefinitions" [value]="ledger.id">
      {{ledger.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The first one the user needs to select a carrier. My goal is that the moment a user selects a carrier, the carrier ID gets passed as parameter to this function:

```
setCarrier(id: number){
    console.log(id);
    this.ratecardService.getSelectedRatecard(id).subscribe(data => this.selectedRatecard = data);
    console.log(this.selectedRatecard);
    //this.updateCurrentValue();
  }
```

This works fine. The console prints the selected id on the first row of this function.
Next I expect that `selectedRatecard` gets assigned with the JSON object that gets returned from:

```
this.ratecardService.getSelectedRatecard(id).subscribe(data => this.selectedRatecard = data);
```

The service class function that gets called looks like this:

```
getSelectedRatecard(id: number): Observable<Ratecard[]>{
        console.log(id);
        return this.http.get<Ratecard[]>('http://localhost:8080//shipmentRate/' + id)

      }
```

Again, the correct number (carrierId) gets printed.

But somehow, after the first selection of the user the line `console.log(this.selectedRatecard);` prints "undefined".

Only after another selection, the console will print the right ratecard that was selected on the first selection. So let's say I select 1 nothing happens (undefined). Then I'll select 2 and the `console.log(id)` prints 2 but the `console.log(this.selectedRatecard);` will print the ratecard of id 1.

Comment: The http call is asynchronous, put the log inside the subscribe

Comment: So how can I make sure the http call is not asynchronous. With other words, the call is done immediatly?

Answer (score 0):

As the http call is async, you could rewrite `setCarrier` to this:

```
setCarrier(id: number){
    console.log(id);
    this.ratecardService.getSelectedRatecard(id)
      .pipe(tap(t => console.log(t))
      .subscribe(data => this.selectedRatecard = data);
  }
```

Then, you can view the logged date within the `tap` and still assign to `selectedRatecard`

you could also use `async/await`:

```
async setCarrier(id: number) {
    const data = await this.ratecardService.getSelectedRatecard(id).toPromise();
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand the problem now. It is not necassary to log the id, but I want the this.ratecard assigned when the user selects the option. So not async. But I do not know how to do that.

Comment: observables are always async, thats their nature, you can in essence create a more sync approach using promises... however, it is still async :)